# Django infinity task

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery

I have infinity task

```
@celeryd_after_setup.connect
def listen_slack_channel(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    sc = SlackClient(settings.SLACK_TOKEN)
    sc.rtm_connect()
    while True:
    ...
```

It workes good but block other tasks... Can you suggest me another way to create infinity task?

Comment: You can assign this task to a separate queue of the worker.

Comment: Thank's. But It doesn't work. I think sygnal still bloking celery

Comment: I've replaced signal to class. `class SlackBot(Task):` How can I run this class on celery startup?